# Getting error while running the program with QAF testrunner with Cucumber

Tags: java, bdd, gherkin, qaf

I'm trying to convert the cucumber-java to Qmetry Automation FrameWork. While running the program, I'm getting the below error message:

> org.testng.TestNGException:  The factory method class
>   com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.ScenarioFactory.getTestsFromFile()
>   threw an exception    at
>   org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:197)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:223)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processMethod(TestNGClassFinder.java:179)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processClass(TestNGClassFinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:121)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:370)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:192)     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:198)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.FactoryMethod.invoke(FactoryMethod.java:167)  ...
>   21 more

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should provide details so someone can reproduce the same issue. Refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html#how-to-use-it